# difference between covariant derivative and connection

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

Is there any difference between covariant derivative and connection, or it is just a case of using two expressions to describe the same thing?

Comment: [Connection (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_%28mathematics%29)